# Convertir Ciclo a función Parallel.For c#

Tags: c#, http-get, task

me podrían ayudar a saber como convertir un ciclo while de una solicitud Get de forma paginada para utilizar parallel.for, ya que no encuentro como hacer la iteración de LstEmpresas.Count.

Lo que se necesito en concreto es solicitar a una api 20,000 registros de forma paginada por medio de un json, es decir una solicitud get con 1,000 registros y hacer la solicitud hasta que la cantidad de registros sean diferente a 0 registros, en ese momento se termina el ciclo, esto lo quiero hacer con solicitudes en paralelo.

Anexo código de ciclo que menciono anteriormente:

```
                oParameters.Pagina = 1;
            var oEmpresas = new Requests<GetEmpresasModelCSharp>();
            var LstGralEmpresas = new List<GetEmpresasModelCSharp>();
            var LstEmpresas = oEmpresas.Connection(oParameters, 1, Method.GET, TokenSesion, PathEmpresas);
            LstGralEmpresas.AddRange(LstEmpresas);
            var TimeInicio = DateTime.Now;
            while (LstEmpresas.Count > 0)
            {
                LstEmpresas = oEmpresas.Connection(oParameters, 1, Method.GET, TokenSesion, PathEmpresas);
                LstGralEmpresas.AddRange(LstEmpresas);
                oParameters.Pagina += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Pagina Impresa --- {0}" , oParameters.Pagina);
            }
```

Lo he intentado hacer pero no me funciona igual que el ciclo, agradezco su apoyo y orientación.

Este es el código que tengo haciendo en paralelo pero yo le tengo que poner la cantidad de paginas que se solicitaran al servidor y ese valor 30 es el que quiero cambiar para que ahi considere detenerse en cuanto LstEmpresas regrese 0 registros.

```
            int i = 0;
            var oEmpresas = new Requests<GetEmpresasModelCSharp>();
            var LstGralEmpresas = new List<GetEmpresasModelCSharp>();
            var LstEmpresas = new List<GetEmpresasModelCSharp>();
            var TimeInicio = DateTime.Now;
            Parallel.For(i,30, (lstEmpresas) =>
                {
                    i++;
                    LstEmpresas = oEmpresas.Connection(oParameters, 1, Method.GET, TokenSesion, PathEmpresas);
                    LstGralEmpresas.AddRange(LstEmpresas);
                    Console.WriteLine("Iterador " + i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Pagina Impresa --- " + oParameters.Pagina + " Soy Hilo" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    oParameters.Pagina = i;
                }
                );
```

Comment: Parallel sirve para realizar multiples llamadas, que es lo que no te funciona? Pero creo que estar casi seguro que te cuenta mal las paginas, porque puede incrementar pero llamar mas tarde y se te saltean los numeros.

Comment: si son las paginas que no me salen ordenadas y aparte que en el ciclo while lo finalizo hasta que el Get no regresa ningún registro, pero no se como hacerlo en el Parallel.For que termine cuando el Get ya no regrese ningún registro, pero que espere a las solicitudes que estan pendientes.

Comment: cual seria el get del que hablas?

Comment: el oEmpresas.Connection es una solicitud a una APi por método Get, la finalidad es realizar una solicitud Get paginada y en paralelo para que sea mas rápido,  ya que actualmente recibe 12,000 objetos en el json y tarda la solicitud mas de 15segundos.

Comment: ok, que demore eso el json, no son muchos registros, si podes deberias ver del lado del servidor porque demora tanto, he recibido mas de 100 mil registros en menos tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel` te lanza la ejecucion en multiples hilos, lo cual no podes controlar cuantos hilos y tampoco que hilos porque eso lo maneja el sistema operativo.
En lugar de ponerle 30, debes pasarle el Count de tu lista.

```
Parallel.For(i, LstEmpresas.Count, (lstEmpresas) =>
{
                i++;
                LstEmpresas = oEmpresas.Connection(oParameters, 1, Method.GET, TokenSesion, PathEmpresas);
                LstGralEmpresas.AddRange(LstEmpresas);              
 });
```

Creo que seria mejor manejar las llamadas por un lado y luego la lectura. Hay varias formas de manejar los multiples hilos pero no entiendo tu caso para leerlos.

```
 private void LeerListadoEmpresas()
 {
    foreach(var items in LstEmpresas)
    {
       //leer registros
    }
 }
```

Comment: Lo que se necesito en concreto es solicitar a una api 20,000 registros de forma paginada por medio de un json, es decir una solicitud get con 1,000 registros y hacer la solicitud hasta que la cantidad de registros sean diferente a 0 registros, en ese momento se termina el ciclo, esto lo quiero hacer con solicitudes en paralelo.